# Mockito equivalent of EasyMock's MockBuilder

Tags: java, mockito, easymock

EasyMock has a function called `createMockBuilder` with which someone can specify a partially mocked class.

Is it possible to do the same with Mockito?

For example in EasyMock some can do the following :

```
classA mockedA = EasyMock.
      createMockBuilder(A.class).
      withConstructor(B.class,C.class).
      withArgs(b,null).
      addMockedMethod("print").
      createMock();
```

Is it possible to do the same with Mockito?

Comment: Throughout your question, is Moquito meant to be Mockito? You've tagged the question that way.

Comment: Ultimately I think you're looking for the [partial mocks capabilities of Mockito](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16)

Comment: @Dan Temple, Yes it is meant to be Mockito !!! Thank for the answer !

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to provide an answer to the your question if the docs helped you to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Mockito does it a little differently from EasyMock. For instance, whereas in EasyMock, you decide which member functions you want mocked:

```
EasyMock.createMockBuilder(A.class).addMockedMethod("foo");
```

in Mockito, all member functions are mocked by default, and you can specify when you want to call an underlying function:

```
A a = Mockito.mock(A.class);
Mockito.when(a.foo()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

If you're wanting to mock only a few member functions with Mockito, I can think of two ways to proceed: The example above, and spying.

```
A a = Mockito.spy(A.class);
Mockito.when(a.foo()).thenReturn("ret");
a.bar(); // Calls the real A.bar() function.
```

Using a spy, member functions are not mocked by default, but can be mocked selectively. See more information here:  http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy